# What's my number?

Tags: logical-deduction, open-ended

I am thinking of an integer $1,2$ or $3$. You can ask me only a single question to which I can reply **"Yes"**, **"No"** or **"I don't know"**. I will be completely honest. What will you ask me to figure out what number I am thinking about?

**Note:** Since there are an infinite number of solutions to this puzzle, I'll select the wittiest one / the one with most upvotes. (Because the one I came up with is kind of overly mathematical and a little too out of the box.)

Comment: The possible duplicate, though very similar, has 4 possible answers (**"maybe"**), which in essence changes the answers.

Comment: "Maybe" can be changed to "I don't know" in almost all circumstances. Besides, there are enough answers on the other question that don't use "maybe" already.

Comment: @AvZ I have a feeling this question is gonna be closed, perhaps you should accept my answer, and tag this as open-ended.

Comment: @warspyking Like I have said before, comments like that make me think you answer for the reputation only.

Comment: @mdc32 My answer was the only understandable one here. Why just leave it unanswered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to think of a random number too, 1 or 2. If we multiply our numbers, will the product be greater than or equal to 3?

- No -> 1
- Yes -> 3
- I don't know -> 2

Comment: Nice, this works. Let's see what others think. I am going to acxept this within a day or 2 if there aren't any other better answers.

Comment: @AvZ If there **is** a better answer I'll just have to get cleverer.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why people downvote "duplicatish" posts.

Comment: @AvZ Yes, because you didn't research enough.

Answer (score 4):

I'm thinking of either 1.5 or 2.5 . Is your number greater than mine?

- Yes          - 3
- No           - 1
- I don't know - 2

Answer (score 2):

> Is either of the following true:
>
> - Your number is $1$.
> - Your number is $2$, and the Riemann hypothesis is true?

If you say "yes", it's 1, if you say "I don't know", it's $2$, and if you say "no", it's $3$. And, if you say "yes" and I find out your number isn't $1$, I'm gonna want a proof.

(You could replace "Riemann hypothesis" by anything else the answerer would not know. For instance, "Is a random number I just thought of equal to $1$?")

Comment: Glad you asked. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137481/i-think-i-have-proved-riemann-hypothesis)

Answer (score 1):

Is the reciprocal of 2 minus your number greater than zero?

- If the number is 1, the answer is YES (as $\frac{1}{2-1}>0$ )
- If the number is 2, the answer is I DON'T KNOW (as $\frac{1}{2-2}$ is undefined  )
- If the number is 3, the answer is NO (as $\frac{1}{2-3}<0$    )

Comment: You generally consider the form $\frac{1}{0}=+\infty$ which is greater than $0$

Comment: @AvZ I would consider $\frac{1}{0} = \pm\infty$, but the other answers are better anyway.